# Are two distinct prime factorizations relatively prime to each other?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, coprime

Consider two integers $x$ and $y$ and their respective prime factorizations
\begin{equation}
x = p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}p_{2}^{\alpha_{2}} \dots p_{n}^{\alpha_{n}}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
y = q_{1}^{\beta_{1}}q_{2}^{\beta_{2}} \dots q_{m}^{\beta_{m}}
\end{equation}

If all of the prime factors above are distinct (i.e. $p_i \neq q_j$ for all $i \neq j$ in  $\{1, 2, \dots, \max(m, n)\}$), then can we say that $x$ and $y$ are co-prime?

I feel like the answer is yes, since (**edit**: the following is incorrect) the only factors of $x$ are the $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n$ and similarly the only factors of $y$ are the $q_1, q_2, \dots, q_m$. But, I'm not sure how this changes when we're considering powers and products of these factors.

Comment: You shouldn't have $p_1$ etc. in both factorizations.  Call those in the factorization of $y$ $q_1,q_2,\dots$.  $x$ and X4Y are relatively prime if and only no prime occurs in both factorizations.

Comment: The only **prime** factors of $P$ are $p_1,\dots,p_n.$

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.  Each integer has only *one* prime factorization and two numbers are relatively prime if they have no factors in common.  That it is necessary and sufficient to show that prime factors of one are distinct from the prime factors of the other.  I think you are wondering about if $a$ divides $m$ and $b$ divide $n$ and $m$ and $n$ are coprime, does that mean $a$ and $b$ are coprime?  The answer is yes.  The prime factors of $a$ are a *subset* of the prime factors of $m$ which are distinct from the prime factors of $b$ which are subset of the prime factors of $n$.

Comment: @fleablood That's very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x,y$ are not coprime. Then they have a common divisor $d$. If $d\mid x$, then the prime factors of $d$ must be selected from $p_i$. Similarly, if $d\mid y$, then the prime factors of $d$ must be selected from $q_j$. But $p_i \ne q_j$, so $d$ has no prime factors; $d=1$ and $x,y$ **are** coprime.